# Update relational table MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables.

**Tables**

[image]

When I insert data to the ekf_parag I do it like this:

```
$ekfonites = $_POST['ekfonites'];

foreach ($ekfonites as $ekfonitis) {
    $parago = $db_con->prepare('SELECT MAX(id) FROM paragoges');
    $parago->execute();
    $paragoges_id = $parago->fetchColumn();
    $ekf = $db_con->prepare('INSERT INTO ekf_parag(id, paragoges_id, ekf_id, ekfonisan) VALUES("", :paragoges_id, :ekfonitis, 0)');
    $ekf->bindParam(':ekfonitis', $ekfonitis);
    $ekf->bindParam(':paragoges_id', $paragoges_id);
    $ekf->execute();
}
```

But when I try to update the table I don't know how to trigger the id from table paragoges. Because it's important (I think) to put the update query inside the foreach, cause there is not only one value in the $ekfonites variable.

Please help me!

Comment: it's strange to me that all ekfonites correspond to the single most recent paragoges_id. if that's true, then you should put your `SELECT MAX(id) FROM paragoges` query before the loop since you only need it once for reuse. could you please provide a translation for "ekfonites" and "paragoges"? google translate wasn't very helpful for me, and I think that context might help clarify your problem. thanks

Comment: I can't put it before the foreach loop. Then, how I'll be able to pass it inside the loop? 

paragoges = productions and ekfonites = broadcasters
which means that one production has many broadcasters

Comment: sure you can, the variable `$paragoges_id` will be available inside the loop. global variables are only needed when using functions or classes - loops have access to the parent variable scope.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger the id from table paragoges"? You are fetching the MAX(id), right? What do you mean by "put the update query"? Do you mean "put the INSERT query"?

Comment: I don't know how to pass a variable in the foreach loop wihtout using it in the condition. How is this possible, when the only variable that passes is the ekfonites as ekfonitis?